# How to show attributes in cart sidebar?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, sidebar

I want to show the configurable attribute ( Size & color) in the cart sidebar. 
This is the coding I entered to show the attribute in the cart popup:

```
<?php if ($_options = $this->getOptionList()):?>
        <div class="truncated">
          <div class="truncated_full_value">
            <dl class="item-options">
                <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <?php if (is_array($_option['value'])): ?>
                    <?php echo nl2br(implode("\n", $_option['value'])) ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $_option['value'] ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </dd>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
          </div>
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="details"><?php echo $this->__('Details') ?></a>
        </div>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

But nothing is showing up. Where have i went wrong?
Please help me to show the color and size of the product in the cart sidebar.

Comment: Where you are placing this code?? Try to add this code on `app/design/frontend/your_default/your_default/template/checkout/cart/item/defaul‌​t.phtml`

Comment: am placing this code in  `cart/sidebar/default.phtml`